# bridge tokio with futures-io::AsyncWrite

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a minimal example with rkyv and [rkyv_codec](https://github.com/zyansheep/rkyv_codec).
This example writes some records to a file and reads them back.

```
use rkyv::{AlignedVec, Archive, Archived, Deserialize, Infallible, Serialize};
use rkyv_codec::{archive_stream, RkyvWriter, VarintLength};
use tokio::{fs::File, io::BufWriter};

#[derive(Archive, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
#[archive(check_bytes)] // check_bytes is required
#[archive_attr(derive(Debug))]
struct Test {
    int: u8,
    string: String,
    option: Option<Vec<i32>>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let value = Test {
        int: 42,
        string: "hello world".to_string(),
        option: Some(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]),
    };

    let mut f = File::open("foo.txt").await.unwrap();
    let mut bf = BufWriter::new(f);

    let mut w = RkyvWriter::<_, VarintLength>::new(bf);
}
```

But the compiler alerts that tokio BufWriter doesn't implement AsyncWrite. I then notices rkyv_codec's AsyncWrite is from futures-io crate.
I need to have this exmaple to work with tokio. How do I bridge tokio's AsyncWrite and futures-io's AsyncWrite?

Comment: Rust beginner here. Have you tried to create your own type from the RkyvWriter and then implement the Tokio AsyncWrite trait on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tokio-util`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/compat/index.html) (an official crate by `tokio`) includes a [`Compat`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/compat/struct.Compat.html) struct that serves as a compatibility layer between `tokio`'s I/O traits and those of `futures`.